# Hauppauge WinTV Ministick doesn't work on 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, firmware, dvb-t

My **Hauppauge WinTV Ministick doesn't work on 16.04.3**.
As the linux-firmware-nonfree isn't supported anymore, I installed the driver myself in /lib/firmware.
I found the file sms1xxx-hcw-55xxx-dvbt-02.fw [here](http://www.hauppauge.de/site/support/support_faq.php?n=FAQ.Linux).

The adapter worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04 with the same firmware (and works today in windows too).
So it is not a problem due to the adapter but it seems to be a problem between the firmware and the new kernel.

The driver **is recognized by dmesg** (see below) but with **kaffeine it doesn't work** :

- It is able to find the channels,
- But when I try to see a channels, the screen becomes blank and the system crashes !

Can someone help me ?

Thank you !

Output of dmesg :

```
[ 7329.648272] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 7329.797205] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2040, idProduct=c000
[ 7329.797212] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7329.797217] usb 2-2: Product: WinTV MiniStick
[ 7329.797221] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Hauppauge Computer Works
[ 7329.797225] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 4033980053
[ 7330.935871] smsusb:smsusb_probe: board id=8, interface number 0
[ 7331.480054] Registered IR keymap rc-hauppauge
[ 7331.480302] input: SMS IR (Hauppauge WinTV MiniStick) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/rc/rc0/input19
[ 7331.480487] rc rc0: SMS IR (Hauppauge WinTV MiniStick) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/rc/rc0
[ 7331.495547] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 241
[ 7331.534345] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (smsmdtv) registered at minor = 0
[ 7331.534348] IR LIRC bridge handler initialized
[ 7331.545973] IR RC5(x/sz) protocol handler initialized
[ 7331.572321] smsusb:smsusb_probe: Device initialized with return code 0
[ 7331.622630] dvbdev: DVB: registering new adapter (Hauppauge WinTV MiniStick)
[ 7331.622816] usb 2-2: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Siano Mobile Digital MDTV Receiver)...
[ 7331.625956] smsdvb:smsdvb_hotplug: DVB interface registered.
[ 7331.626439] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsusb
```

Output of lsusb :

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2040:c000 Hauppauge Windham
```

Comment: I have an old computer [https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/toshiba_satellite_p300-27z] with a windows Vista dual boot and no UEFI bios.

Comment: You should then open Additional drivers. If additional firmware is required it should be offered.

Comment: Here is the output of
`meloli@portable:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list` gives
`intel-microcode`
Nothing linked with my hauppauge stick ...
I've tried to remove the file `sms1xxx-hcw-55xxx-dvbt-02.fw` which I putted in \lib\firwmare. Same answer from ` ubuntu-drivers list`.